# $_FILES array is empty

Tags: php, file

This is the first time I am trying to upload a file and for some reason my $_FILES array is empty. I have checked again and again my HTML and it looks okay to me. When i try to debug the below code in eclipse the $_Files array is empty when i check it. I have checked the php_ini file it has:

- file_uploads = On
- upload_max_filesize = 2M

The form is in a fancybox modal window.
My HTML looks like this:

```
<form  action="/CiREM/attachments/addAttachmentsModal.php?requestId=120" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="addattachment" name="addattachment" class="form-vertical" autocomplete="off">
        <input type='hidden' id='requestId' name='requestId' value="120"/>
        <input type='hidden' id='listScreen' name='listScreen' value=""?>   
        <input type='hidden' name='MAX_FILE_SIZE' value='4000000' /><br/> <strong>Max File size Allowed: </strong>4 Mb <br/><strong>File Formats Allowed: </strong>gif,jpeg,jpg,png<br/><hr/>               <div class="control-group">


                <div class="controls input">
                    <input class="input-file" type="file" name="upload_file[]" id="upload_file[]"/><br/>
                </div>
                </div>
                    <input class="input-file" type="file" name="upload_file[]" id="upload_file[]"/><br/>
                </div>
                </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class ="clear"></div>
                        <input id="addAttachmentsBtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" value="Add Attachments"/>
                    </form>
```

My php is

```
<form  action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?requestId=".$requestId?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="addattachment" name="addattachment" class="form-vertical" autocomplete="off">
        <input type='hidden' id='requestId' name='requestId' value="<?php echo $requestId;?>"/>
        <input type='hidden' id='listScreen' name='listScreen' value="<?php echo $listScreen;?>"?>  
        <?php 
        if ($CIREM['MAX_IMG_NUM']>0){
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='MAX_FILE_SIZE' value='".$CIREM['MAX_IMG_SIZE']."' />";
            echo "<br/> <strong>Max File size Allowed: </strong>".($CIREM['MAX_IMG_SIZE']/1000000)." Mb <br/><strong>File Formats Allowed: </strong>".$CIREM['IMG_TYPES']."<br/><hr/>";?>

        <?php   for ($i=1;$i<=$CIREM['MAX_IMG_NUM'];$i++){?>


                <div class="controls input">
                    <input class="input-file" type="file" name="upload_file[]" id="upload_file[]"/><br/>
                </div>

            <?php }?>

        <?php }
        else{
            echo "<p class='alert alert-info'>Attachment uploading is not allowed</p>";
        }
        ?>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Shakira

Comment: Your PHP just outputs what appears to be a similar form as your HTML. Where's the code that actually has the problem?

Comment: I think it would be to your (and everyone else's) benefit to remove the unnecessary stuff to make this comprehnsible. For example, `<div class ="clear"></div>` has got nothing to do with this. All it does is complicate the question. Also, it looks like you're just showing us 2 forms, the word `$_FILES` isn't even in your code... Also in your post body you are referencing `$_Files` which is not correct.

Comment: Where is the code that actually processes the files that are uploaded?

Comment: I don't think `id="upload_file[]"` is valid HTML, but I doubt that would cause your problems.

Comment: Don't you need to specify `method="post"`?

Comment: I updated the code to remove unnecessary stuff.

Comment: Yes there is method=post...didnt copy it here...

Answer (score 0):

Without looking through that spaghetti code, first check whether your $_POST is also empty.

If it is, make sure that post_max_size is larger than upload_max_filesize. The two settings have to be congruent.

Comment: I just did that but it didnt work. Will it help if i look at php logs?

Answer (score 0):

First of all sorry for the late reply but since sometimes people stumble upon old topics on stackoverflow, I decided to write the way it works for me.

So, to send files via ajax you have to use FormData.

I'll paste a link to a github project I have to submit forms via ajax so you can check the working example and paste here the snippet.

Link: https://github.com/pihh/auto-ajax-form

Code:

```
$( "form" ).on('submit',function( event ) {
        if($(this).attr('ajax')){
            event.preventDefault();
            var marianaFormUrl = $(this).attr('action');
            var marianaFormId = $(this).attr('id');
            var marianaFormMethod = $(this).attr('type');
            var marianaFormSucess = $(this).attr('success');
            var marianaFormComplete = $(this).attr('complete');
            var marianaFormBefore = $(this).attr('before');
            var marianaFormInputs = $('#' + marianaFormId +' :input');
            var marianaEncType = $(this).attr('enctype');
            var marianaFormData = {};

            // Set enctype
            if(marianaEncType === undefined || marianaEncType == ''){
                $(this).attr('enctype','multipart/form-data');
            }

            // Run Ajax Call
            $.ajax({
                url: marianaFormUrl,
                type: marianaFormMethod,
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: new FormData( this ),
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                success:function(data){
                    // Run success
                    if(marianaFormSucess !== undefined && marianaFormSucess !== ''){
                        var fn = marianaFormSucess;
                        var func = fn +'( data )';
                        eval(func);
                    }
                },
                complete:function(data){
                    // Run complete
                    if(marianaFormComplete !== undefined && marianaFormComplete !== ''){
                        var fn = marianaFormComplete;
                        var func = fn +'( data )';
                        eval(func);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

This is it, using formData it sends the files just fine.